# Prove with natural deduction

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Prove P ∨ Q, Q ∨ R, P → ¬R |- Q with natural deduction.

1. P ∨ Q, premiss
2. Q ∨ R, premiss
3. P → ¬R, premiss
   ...
   ...
   Conclusion, Q

I dont know how to properly solve this question?

I know somewhat how to solve similar questions like below, but on this specific question above I dont know where to start.

[image]

Comment: This should be asked on Mathematics, not here.

Comment: The idea is to do OR-elimination. The intuition behind OR-elimination is that you're going to do a case analysis. If you choose to eliminate $p \lor q$, you will first consider the possibility that $p$ is true, and then consider the possibility that $q$ is true. The meaning of the rule is that regardless of whether $p$ or $q$ is true, you must reach the same conclusion either way. That's the idea of OR-elimination. So that's your first step. And that's what you see in the proof in lines 3 and 5. Reply if you have other questions.